# Django: Error Setting Up Project

Tags: python, django

The command - `c:\>python django-admin.py install`

returns

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

I have included both python and django binaries in PATH(Windows)

python-

```
"C:\Python27\";
```

django-

```
"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\bin\"
```

but the same works fine if the path of `"django-admin.py"` is specified instead.

Comment: `python` doesn't check PATH to find scripts. You need to be in the right working directory, or specify the full path to the script.

Comment: You have to execute that command where your application/project resides (look for the folder that contains a manage.py file in it)

Comment: @Wooble Okay, i thought working directory didnt matter, my bad. thanks :)

Comment: @karthikr i got this error when current directory was the folder containing manage.py

Comment: What? `C:\` has `manage.py` ?

Comment: `C:\Users\Har\Desktop\bleh\mysite>` this

Comment: Using django from windows is hell. Take this for your future questions http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

You should put `django-admin.py` in your `%PATH%` directory, and launch it directly without `python`before.

More explanation about `PATH` [here](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).